# ldap3 extend.microsoft.modify_password keeps returning false

Tags: python, python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, ldap3

I'm trying to modify an user account password in but it doesn't work, I've tried it directly in AD and it does work. I'm using ldap3 to do it, here's the steps I do.

First I do the app operation like this

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
s = Server("ldap://192.168.x.xx", use_ssl=True)
c = Connection(s, user='adminldap', password='xxxxxxx')
c.bind()
c.add('cn=jtest,ou=users,ou=MJC,dc=mjc,dc=lan', ['user', 'posixGroup', 'top'], {'cn': 'jtest', 'sAMAccountName':'jtest', 'mail':'jtest@gmail.com','telephoneNumber':'0102030405','displayName':'jtest'})
```

This one works.

Then I try to set the password

```
Path_Root = "ou=users,ou=MJC,DC=mjc,DC=lan"
Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(&(sAMAccountName=jtest)(!(objectclass=computer))))"
c.search(search_base = Path_Root,search_filter = Filter,attributes = ["cn", "sAMAccountName", "displayName"])
if len(c.entries) == 1:
   USER_DN = c.response[0].get("dn")
   c.extend.microsoft.modify_password(USER_DN, 'Formation123')
```

Like this but the last line keeps returning False.

Have you got an idea why ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was setting ssl on my ldap and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues/891#issuecomment-733904441):

> I looked into the source and it says old password must be None to reset password with sufficient privileges

This should work:

```
 c.extend.microsoft.modify_password(USER_DN, 'Formation123', old_password=None)
```

And the connection has to be encrypted. You may have to specify `ldaps://` even though you specified `use_ssl`, since the LDAPS port (636) is different than the regular LDAP port (389).

```
s = Server("ldaps://192.168.x.xx", use_ssl=True)
```

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work and when I put  ```"ldaps://192.168.x.xx"``` it returns errors

Comment: So, I think I figured out, why I can't connect with ssl. It was not configured on my server, I'll try it, and then comeback here to tell you if it was ok

Comment: Hi @Fujah, Have you found a solution ? Please share your findings.

Comment: Yes,the solution was  setting ssl on ldap and accessing with ldaps://192.168.x.xx